# Defining a macro to evaluate a polynomial

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to define a macro to evaluate a polynomial x^5-3x^3+4. Here is what I have so far. It compiles but does not print the correct value. Instead it gives 4 as the answer. I don't have much experience with C and nothing I've tried has made it work. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define F_OF_X(x) (pow(x,5)-(3*pow(x,3))+4)

int main (){

    float n;

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &n);

    printf("%.2f\n\n", F_OF_X(n));

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `%lf` should be `%f` in the `scanf` as the former is used for a `double`,not a `float` and include `stdlib.h` for `pow`

Comment: While you're fixing that, maybe check the result `scanf` to ensure you actually read a valid `float` in the first place.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In `scanf()`, `%lf` expects a pointer to `double`. you Need to use `%f` for `float`s.